# Wrong output when printing a string from inside a struct pointer (VC++ 2010)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, printf

I've found a very strange issue with both printf (and printf_s), and also std::cout. I'm not sure if it's some short of "glitch" or error in these functions, or if I'm doing something wrong. Since both functions do the same, I'm assuming I'm not doing it the right way.

I have the following structures in my program (By the way, this is a Visual C++ 2010 project):

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct nameentry
{
    char NAME[17];
    char EXT[4];
}NAMEENTRY;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct fileentry
{
    unsigned int ID;
    NAMEENTRY FILENAME;
    unsigned int GPFID;
    unsigned long long int FPOINTER;
    size_t FILESIZE;
}FILEENTRY;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Now I have the following portion of code:

```
NAMEENTRY fname = MCreateNameEntry("LONGFILE.JPG");
FILEENTRY* myfile_ = SearchFileByPkgID(0, fname);
printf("%s", myfile_->FILENAME.NAME);
```

So what this code is supposed to do is, create an instance of NAMEENTRY with NAME=LONGFILE, and EXT=JPG. Both character arrays are null terminated (last byte is a 0). Then create an instance of FILEENTRY with it's corresponding data from a database I'm developing, then print the name of the file from the FILEENTRY's NAMEENTRY structure.

After running the code, what I get instead of the name of the file, is... garbage. The classic garbage you get when trying to print text from a bad pointer. If I try to print any of the other fields, I also get wrong values.

So obviously, my first thought was that one of my functions were not returning the right value. So I started inspecting the code and, to my surprise, they are actually returning the right values and the structure is filled with the right data. I get the proper values in each field, every character array ends with a 0, etc.

So then I said... "What if I copy the entire block into another instance of FILEENTRY?", and I tried this:

```
NAMEENTRY fname = MCreateNameEntry("LONGFILE.JPG");
FILEENTRY* myfile_ = SearchFileByPkgID(0, fname);
FILEENTRY dMem;

memcpy(&dMem, myfile_, sizeof(FILEENTRY));

printf("%s", dMem.FILENAME.NAME);
```

And guess what? It works perfectly fine. I get the name of the file, no garbage.  So I'm assuming, either the problem is inside of printf (I also tried std::cout with the same results), or I am doing something wrong when using these functions.

Comment: You probably have UB somewhere. Impossible to tell without a complete testcase.

Comment: lol manual memory management and memcpy. The fact that you even attempted that workaround suggests that something is terribly broken and you could well be responsible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not a workaround. That's a way to tell if said memory block is correct. If  the last line of code also gave me wrong values then yes, something would be terribly broken. However, in this case, it works. So the real workaround until a proper answer is given would be, either return a instance of FILEENTRY instead of a pointer, or using a custom text output function to prnt each character.

Comment: I predict that `SearchFileByPkgID` returns an address of a local variable. As long as you haven't called any other function, that now-unused area of the stack retains its previous contents, and you can copy data away from it (note that this exhibits undefined behavior - you are accessing an object after its lifetime has ended). When you call another function - e.g. `printf` - the stack gets overwritten with that function's local variables, which looks to you like your structure is suddenly filled with garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that helps. Seems like the problem was trying to return a pointer to a local variable, as Igor Tandetnik suggested.

So as a workaround, I'm not sure if this is a proper way of handling this, instead of define a local variable, I'm using calloc to allocate a memory block for a FILEENTRY pointer, then fill it and return it. And yes, it seems to work this way.

This is the actual code of the function:

```
FILEENTRY* SearchFileByPkgID(int ID, NAMEENTRY fname)
{
    FILEENTRY* myFile = (FILEENTRY*)calloc(sizeof(FILEENTRY),1);
    std::vector<int> results;
    unsigned int* dptable = GetDPTableByPkgId(ID);
    bool found = false;

    for(int x = 0; x < 1024; x++)
    {
        if(dptable[x] > 0)
        {
            fseek(PDBFILE, dptable[x], SEEK_SET);
            fread(myFile, sizeof(FILEENTRY), 1, PDBFILE);
            if(strcmp(myFile->FILENAME.EXT, fname.EXT) == 0)
                if(myFile->FILENAME.NAME[0] == fname.NAME[0])
                    results.push_back(dptable[x]);
        }
    }


    for(int y = 0; y < results.size(); y++)
    {
        fseek(PDBFILE, results[y], SEEK_SET);
        fread(myFile, sizeof(FILEENTRY), 1, PDBFILE);
        if(strcmp(myFile->FILENAME.NAME, fname.NAME) == 0)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    results.clear();

    if(found)
        return myFile;
    else
        return 0L;
}
```

Any more suggestions are wellcome.

Comment: Note: 1) Recommend checking the results of `fseek(), fread()` to insure data was read as expected. 2) Change to `else { free(myFile); return 0L;}`